# sending image file to controller action method in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying this code to call controller action method "NewReport" by taking image from user. It does call the controller function but inside controller when I am trying to use this file to convert into binary it says its null.

```
<h2>Basic File Upload</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("NewReport", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"})
{
    <label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" />
    <br><br>
    @ViewBag.Message
}
```

Comment: Please post your controller action method too.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public byte[] NewReport(string filename)
        {

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] image = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            

        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action method is incorrect, it's not the filename that gets posted to you, it's the actual byte content. Instead, try something like this:

```
public ActionResult NewReport(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // Do something with the file here
    var fileName = file.FileName;
    var fileContentStream = file.InputStream;

    //Store the file on your webserver
    file.SaveAs(string.Format(@"c:\somefolder\{0}", file.FileName);

    return View();
}
```

Comment: But then wouldn't it save data in my pc like inside a folder in c in ur case. I want it to get saved in sql server database in a table column named ImageContent

Comment: Actually what I want to do is to first call action method. Inside that action method I would convert file into byte content or binary and then save it into sql server database.

Comment: @user3532152 My code saves it to the drive, you don't have to do that. Take the byte stream from `file.InputStream` and insert the data from there into your database.

Comment: @user3532152 If you want help with doing that, please open another question. This one was only to get the file into an action method.

Comment: Thank you so much .Images are being saved in my drive .